# How to cache (entire table or results of Domain.list() method) in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, caching

I have a small table SYMBOLS, which is used to populate a dropdown on ui. As this table contains mostly static data, I want to cache its contents.

My problem is that every time a method Symbol.list() is invoked, it results in a query execution on the database.

Domain class:

```
package com.perseus.ui.model

class Symbol implements Serializable, Comparable<Symbol> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

String exchange
String symbol
String description
int index

static constraints = {
    exchange(nullable:false, blank: false)
    symbol(nullable:false, blank: false)
    description(nullable:false, blank: false)
}

static mapping = {
    id composite: ['exchange', 'symbol']
    table 'Symbols'
    cache 'read-only'
}

String toString() {
    return description
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((exchange == null) ? 0 : exchange.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((symbol == null) ? 0 : symbol.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Symbol other = (Symbol) obj;
    if (exchange == null) {
        if (other.exchange != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!exchange.equals(other.exchange))
        return false;
    if (symbol == null) {
        if (other.symbol != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!symbol.equals(other.symbol))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Symbol o) {
    int result = 0
    if(this.index)
        result = -1
    else if(o.index) {
        result = 1
    } else {
        result = this.symbol.compareTo(o.symbol)
    }
    return result;
}


}
```

resources.groovy

```
// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
xmlns cache: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache'
xmlns aop: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop'

importBeans('classpath:config/beans.xml')

cache.'advice'(id: 'symbolCacheAdvice',
        'cache-manager': 'grailsCacheManager') {
        caching(cache: 'symbols') {
            cacheable(method: 'list')
        }
    }

aop.config {
    advisor('advice-ref': 'symbolCacheAdvice',
        pointcut: 'execution(* com.perseus.ui.model.Symbol.*(..))')
}

}
```

UI Element: `<g:select name="symbol" from="${Symbol.list(readOnly: true)}" optionKey="symbol" />`

I have tried following options, but none of them seem to be working:

1. Hibernate second level cache : Objects are cached, but Symbol.list() always hits the database.
2. Enabled query cache : Did not help
3. Marked Symbols.list() method @Cachable : Surprisingly even this did not work. Please see resources.groovy.

I believe this is very common use case, what would be the best way to implement this? One obvious solution is to cache it manually, but that doesn't sound good.

Comment: I would suggest you instead look at using the Grails cache plugin, as you can see from the documentation it's fairly easy to configure and use: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/guide/usage.html

Comment: Hi Joshua, I have already tried that, please check option 3 and resources.groovy; it didn't work.

Comment: I didn't see that you were using the actual plugin itself, but rather spring cache. My apologies if you already tried the actual plugin. I've had great success with it personally.

Comment: Have you tried the plug-in on auto-generated methods? Symbol.list() method is auto generated by grails, and I could not use annotations .

Comment: I wouldn't ever annotate the domain directly, I would use a proper service layer and annotate that.

Answer (score 4):

In general, avoid using the cache plugin for GORM query results - Hibernate's 1st and 2nd-level caches are very reliable and resistent to stale data bacause they flush cached data when it's possible that those results could have been affected by a change. But if you use Ehcache directly, or a wrapper API like Spring Cache or the Grails plugins, you have to know when to invalidate data, and that can be a hard problem.

If you plan on accessing the cached data only through the `list()` method, which makes sense since it will all be in-memory, then you  want a variant that uses the Query Cache, and it must be enabled in DataSource.groovy:

```
hibernate {
   cache.use_second_level_cache = true
   cache.use_query_cache = true
   ...
}
```

`list()` doesn't have a caching option, you can run an equivalent criteria query that does:

```
def symbols = Symbol.createCriteria().list {
   cache true
}
```

If you want to access the items by ID, run a query to get all of the ids, then loop through that at startup and call `Symbol.get(id)` for each. Individual instances are cached in their own caches, not in the query cache, so they're less likely to be invalidated early.

Also note that you need to configure the underlying cache implementation and configure the cache size, elements in memory, spillover to disk, etc. The default TTL in Ehcache is 120 seconds - that's only 2 minutes. But if you rarely or never edit/create/delete these, then cache as long as you want.

Comment: Thanks Burt,

So caching the criteria query result will only cache ids of the Symbol domain class and not the entire object? Just want to understand why we need to call `Symbol.get(id)` explicitly for each object.

Comment: I applied grails cache plugin and added a service layer. Marked the service layer methods @Cacheable and its working fine.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith : I tried the above code (cache true) in withCriteria, doesn't seems  any difference in performance, the same milliseconds need to  get the result with  and without caching.